# kinect v1 realtime point cloud data in unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect, point-clouds

Is it possible to display point cloud data in Unity3D with Kinect V1, the same way it has been done with Kinect (Fusion) V2?

Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aiLtnapMDcU

Any advice how to display it would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does anyone have any idea? At least some hints to start drawing 320x240 points matrix in Unity so I could assign every point to a depth data from Kinect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I recommend you check this out from the asset store https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/7747